# Find all pairs of values $a$ and $b$ that satisfy $(a+bi)^2 = 48 + 14i$

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all pairs of values $a$ and $b$ that satisfy $(a+bi)^2 = 48 + 14i$

Here's what I have so far:

$$\begin{align}
z^2 &= 48 + 14i = 50 \operatorname{cis} 0.2837\\
z &= \sqrt{50} \operatorname{cis} 0.1419 = 7 + i \\
z &= \sqrt{50} \operatorname{cis} 3.2834 = -7 - i\\
a &= ± 7 \\
b &= ± 1
\end{align} $$

What are the other solutions, and how do I find them?

Comment: You have already too many 'solutions:' $(7-i)^2 = 48-14i$. Remember that you are seeking the zeroes of a quadratic polynomial, which has two zeroes.

Comment: So a,b must have the same sign, but, according to my book there are imaginary solutions... where did these come from?

Comment: Then you book is wrong. There cannot be (pure) imaginary solutions, this would mean $a=0$. Maybe they mean complex, but all your solutions are already complex because $b\ne 0$.

Comment: I meant that a and b are imaginary... I can see how it works out but how would I have found those methodically?

Comment: No $a, b$ are **real**. The method to find the two solutions $z_1,z_2$ is simple and you have almost done it:
$z_{1,2} = \pm \sqrt{48+14i}=\pm(7+i)$. The square root is the so-called principle square root and you computed it as your first $z$.

Comment: The method in the book starts with a^2 - b^2 = 48, doesn't this work out that a,b can be imaginary?

Comment: No, this must be explicitly stated. The standard convention is that for the complex number $a+bi$ the parts $a,b$ are real numbers called the real and imaginary part. But of course you can give somewhat confusing representations like
$7+i = (i) - (7i)i.$

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

$$48+14i=(a+ib)^2=a^2-b^2+i(2ab)$$

Equating the imaginary parts, $2ab=14\iff ab=7$

Equating the real parts, $a^2-b^2=48$

$(a^2+b^2)^2=(a^2-b^2)^2+(2ab)^2=48^2+14^2=50^2$

$\iff a^2+b^2=50$ as $a,b$ are real

and we have $a^2-b^2=48$

Solve for $a^2,b^2$

As $ab=7>0\implies a,b$ will have the same sign

Comment: Hi, actually, what I meant to ask is why one of the solutions given is a = ±i, b = ∓7i. (I have not come across ∓ sign before - how is it different from ±?)

Comment: @Wooneh, $$-(\pm)=\mp$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(a+bi\right)^2=48+14i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left(a+bi\right)\left(a+bi\right)=48+14i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$a^2-b^2+2abi=48+14i$$

Now, see that:

- $$\Re\left(a^2-b^2+2abi\right)=48\Longleftrightarrow a^2-b^2=48$$
- $$\Im\left(a^2-b^2+2abi\right)=14\Longleftrightarrow 2ab=14\Longleftrightarrow ab=7$$

  ---

Now, solve this system for the real and complex solutions:

$$
\begin{cases}
a^2-b^2=48\\
ab=7
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
a^2-b^2=48\\
b=\frac{7}{a}
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
a^2-\left(\frac{7}{a}\right)^2=48\\
b=\frac{7}{a}
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
a^2-\frac{49}{a^2}=48\\
b=\frac{7}{a}
\end{cases}
$$